# Shift the cursor focus on to a textField on checkbox selection

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have a text field and a check box.On selection of the combo box the cursor irrespective of its position should come to the text field.Is it possible

If yes how can it be done in gwt

Comment: Do you actually want to move the mouse cursor or just set the focus onto the text field?

Comment: I want the focus to be in the text field which i have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
final TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

checkBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Boolean>()
{
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> event)
    {
        /* Do something with the event */

        /* Then set the focus */
        textBox.setFocus(true);
    }
});
```